# d3 - Add single line to grouped bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I build by grouped bar chart and it is working great. Now I need to add a single line to the graph that represents a percentage of the service hours against the hours worked. My data is sent by JSON:

```
[{"SORT_NAME":"WEEMS, AMY",
"Service":118.0,
"Available":40.0,
"Timesheet":28.0,
"Month":3,
"MonthName":"Mar",
"Year":2017},
{"SORT_NAME":"WEEMS, AMY",
"Service":119.0,
"Available":80.0,
"Timesheet":70.0,
"Month":4,
"MonthName":"Apr",
"Year":2017}]
```

And processed by d3 in HTML:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // set the dimensions of the canvas
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40 },
        width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    // set the ranges
    var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
    var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();
    var xl = d3.scale.linear().range([0,width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var z = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#0b4a72", "#ad1a2c", "#7aa74d"]);

    // define the axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x0)
        .orient("bottom")


    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(10);

    // add the SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // load the data
    d3.json("http://lrssrs/LRCS/EmpHours/GraphData", function (error, data) {

        var seriesNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (key) { return (key !== "SORT_NAME") && (key !== "Year") && (key !== "Month") && (key !== "MonthName"); });

        data.forEach(function (d) { d.Hours = seriesNames.map(function (name) { return { name: name, value: +d[name] }; }); });

        // scale the range of the data
        x0.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.MonthName + " " + d.Year; }));
        x1.domain(seriesNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
        xl.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.MonthName + " " + d.Year; }));
        y.domain([0, (10 + d3.max(data, function (d) { return d3.max(d.Hours, function (d) { return d.value; }); }))]); 
        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) {
              return xl(d.Available);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
              return y(d.Service / d.Timesheet);
            });     

        svg.append("path")
            .attr("d", line(data));

        // add axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", "-.55em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 5)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Hours");

        var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "g")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.MonthName + " " + d.Year) + ",0)"; });

        // Add bar chart
        state.selectAll("bar")
            .data(function (d) { return d.Hours; })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function (d) { return x1(d.name); })
            .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); })
            .style("fill", function (d) { return z(d.name); });

        state.selectAll("text")
            .data(function (d) { return d.Hours; })
            .enter().append("text")
            .text(function (d) { return d.value; })
            .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
            .attr("x", function (d) { return x1(d.name) + (x1.rangeBand() / 2); })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value) + 20; })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", "11px")
            .attr("fill", "white");

        var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
            .data(seriesNames.slice().reverse())
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0," + (i * 20) + ")"; });

        legend.append("rect")
            .attr("x", width - 18)
            .attr("width", 18)
            .attr("height", 18)
            .style("fill", z);

        legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", width - 24)
            .attr("y", 9)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text(function (d) { return d; })
            .on("click", function (d) { alert(d); });

    });

</script>
```

However, I can't seem to get the line to generate and I keep getting a path attribute error (Expected number). How do I set up the the line data? If someone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it!

Comment: You need linear scales for lines. Create another x scale that's linear.

Comment: Added that to my code above. I've tested it, but I am still not getting the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up having to completely re-write this d3 script in order to make it work. I found this example: https://bl.ocks.org/nanu146/f48ffc5ec10270f55c9e1fb3da8b38f0.

I had to update my json to make an array, but now it all works great.

Comment: Can we add plots to the line chart here?

Comment: I asked the same question! Check out this SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972727/add-data-points-and-text-to-lines-on-a-multi-bar-graph-with-lines