# Add data points and text to lines on a multi-bar graph with lines

Tags: d3.js

I used the d3 pre-built chart found here:

https://bl.ocks.org/nanu146/f48ffc5ec10270f55c9e1fb3da8b38f0

It works great and everything is pulling the way it is supposed to. However, it's been requested that the lines have data points added with the text of the value for each point above it.

I have placed some code for text here:

```
svg.selectAll(".lines")
                .classed('labels-group', true)
                .data(lineData)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .each(function (d) {
                    Name = d[0].name
                    d3.select(this)
                        .append("path")
                        .attr("d", function (b) { return line(b) })
                        .style({ "stroke-width": "3px", "fill": "none" })
                        .style("stroke", LineColor(Name))
                        .transition()
                        .duration(1500)
                        .append('text')
                        .classed('label', true)
                        .attr({
                          'x': function(d, i) {
                            return x(d.name);
                          },
                          'y': function(d, i) {
                            return y(d.value);
                          }
                        })
                        .text(function(d, i) {
                          return d.value;
                        });

                })
```

That makes one line disappear, however. Am I placing this in the wrong spot or am I missing something to tell the code to finish with the line and continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Firstly, a minor and quick glitch in the line coloring is due to this `Name = d[0].name` where `d` has no attribute as **name** but does have one as **Name** (capital N)

   ```
   Name = d[0].Name;
   ```
2. Now, the main issue with your code is that you're trying to append `text` to the `path` which would never work. The way you should do is:

   ```
   var lines = d3.select(this)
     .append("path")
     .attr("d", function (b) { return line(b) })
     .style({ "stroke-width": "3px", "fill": "none" })
     .style("stroke", LineColor(Name))
     .transition().duration(1500);

   var texts = d3.select(this).selectAll('text.value')
      .....
   ```
3. Using the logic in #2, append the texts for each element in `d` and assign `x`, `y` and `text` accordingly. Here's how:

   ```
   var texts = d3.select(this).selectAll('text.value')
                .data(d)
                .enter().append('text')
                .classed('label', true)
                .attr('dy', '-1em')
                .text(function (d) {
                   return d.Value;
                })                    
                .attr({
                  'x': function(d, i) {
                        var width = d3.select(this).node().getBBox().width;
                        return x0(d.Date) + x0.rangeBand() / 2 - width/2;
                       },
                  'y': function(d, i) {
                        return YLine(d.Value);
                       }
                   });
   ```

   If you notice the above code, I'm assigning the `text` first and then applying `x` based on the **width** of the text using [getBBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement) to center the text at the point. Feel free to adjust `dy`, `dx` according to your requirements.

   Putting together all of the above, here's a fork of that code:

   https://bl.ocks.org/shashank2104/2acfdd38dc262285d2c736ba86dbc1ad/11380be2e4c095808231056930d6860f97722254

   Hope this helps. And if you're up for suggestions, please refer [this](https://bl.ocks.org/pstuffa/26363646c478b2028d36e7274cedefa6) for adding data-points to a line chart.

Comment: Excellent! I had tried something like this first, but it didn't change anything on the graph, so I assumed I was going the wrong way. Thanks Shashank!

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help :)